# How to store a subroutine to a variable in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, subroutine

I am trying to prove that you can store subroutines inside a variable (unless you can't). Any chance that I just have this code all wrong?

[I have this code from Python that does what I want to do](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjn2e.png)

```
def printSample(str)   
   puts str 
end  
x = printSample 
str = "Hello" 
x(str)
```

expected output:

> Hello

*I am a beginner in Ruby and just trying to learn basic codes.*

Comment: Define what you mean by _subroutine_ in the context of Ruby. In Ruby, you have: Instance methods, class methods, and closures. All of them can be handled via a variable.

Comment: @user1934428 if i'm not mistaken, the method (in this case, printSample) is the subroutine. 

Here is the specific question asked by my instructor: Can subroutines be stored in variables?

Comment: I gave an anwer for an instance method. Actually for a method as the one written by you, a class method would perhaps be more appropriate, but it is an artificial example anyway. Since you don't have _subroutines_ in Ruby (you won't find this word in the Ruby language definition), the question is meaningless anyway, unless you define exactly what is meant by it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example for handling an instance method:

```
class Demo
  def initialize(s); @s = s; end
  def printSample(str); puts(@s+str); end
end

x = Demo.instance_method(:printSample)
# x is now of class UnboundMethod

aDemo = Demo.new("Hi")

# Use x
x.bind(aDemo).call("You")  # Outputs: HiYou
```

In this example, we first stored the method, and then applied it to an instance. If you have the instance first and want to fetch the method later, it is even simpler. Assuming the class definition of `Demo` from above, you can equally well do a

```
aDemo = Demo.new("Hi")
y = aDemo.method(:printSample)
y.call("You")
```

Comment: Tested your code and replaced line#6 with x = Demo.instance_method(:printSample). It worked afterwards. Thanks.

Comment: I will fix it. When I played with it in irb, i used `C` for brevity and forgot to fix it when copying.

Comment: @lowrain : I have added an alternative solution for completeness. Depending on what exactly you want to do, one or the other will be more suitable.

Answer (score 5):

Your Python code can be translated to Ruby as:

```
def print_sample(str)
  puts str
end

x = method(:print_sample)
str = "Hello"
x.(str)
```

The main difference is that because parentheses in Ruby are optional, writing `x = print_sample` would already invoke the method. Retrieving a [Method](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Method.html) object that you can call later is a little more involved: you have to call [`method`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Object.html#method-method) and pass the method name as a symbol or string. (the receiver being the object the method is defined in)

And because method objects are regular objects, the syntax for actually calling the method is also slightly different. Ruby provides:

```
x[str]
x.(str)
x.call(str)
```

With `x.(str)` being syntactic sugar for `x.call(str)`, see [`Method#call`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Method.html#call-method)

---

Another approach is to just store the method name and to invoke the method dynamically via [`send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Object.html#send-method) / [`public_send`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-3.0.2/Object.html#public_send-method), e.g.:

```
x = :print_sample
str = "Hello"
send(x, str)
```

Referring to methods via their (symbolized) name is quite idiomatic in Ruby.